# Can I restrict Swift Package Manager to only particular platform?

Tags: swift

Thanks to Xcode 11 I can create a UIKit-based component as a standalone package. I used Swift Package Manager and everything seems to be fine, but can I restrict `Package.swift` to be iOS only?

There is no point in my package being available for macOS or Linux because there is no `UIKit` and it will not compile.

Any suggestions on how to do that? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

To my experience, You can't restrict a package. But you can specify platforms:

> **Apple**: 
>   Swift packages are platform-independent by nature and include Linux as a target platform

Use conditional compilation blocks to handle platform-specific code and/or achieve cross-platform compatibility.

```
#if os(Linux)

// Code specific to Linux

#elseif os(macOS)

// Code specific to macOS

#endif
```